# getting different scaling in sklearn grid search

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series, pipeline, grid-search

I'm trying to set a `GridSearchCV` in sklearn that uses a `TimeSeriesSplit` with data normalized on the **training** set. What I did is to create a `TransformerMixin` called `DivisorTransform` that gets the divisor of the normalization and store it. The `DivisorTransform` is instantiated before the `Pipeline`. Into the pipeline, I set the `DivisorTransform` (in order to fit it) and then a `NormalizeTransformer` takes as input the `DivisorTransform` and perform the division. However, using this pipeline into the `GridSearchCV` the transformer are pickled. This causes the `DivisorTransform` to be pickled and fitted, then the `NormalizeTransformer` is pickled but having the `DivisorTransform` in itself, the `DivisorTransform` is pickled again. This causes the `NormalizeTransformer` to use un un-fitted `DivisorTransform`.
Here is an example

```
dt = DivisorTransform()
pipe = Pipeline([('divisor',dt),('normalize',NormalizeTransformer(dt))])
gridS = GridSearchCV(pipe,params={...},cv=TimeSeriesSplit())
```

How different normalizations have to be managed into a `GridSearchCV`? Which are the best practice?

Here a python example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit

class DivisorTransform(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        print(f'{type(self).__name__} id {id(self)} fit')
        self.divisor_ = X.max()
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        print(f'{type(self).__name__} id {id(self)} transform')
        return X

    def getDivisor(self):
        return self.divisor_

class NormalizationTransform(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, divisorTransform, fakeParam):
        self.divTrns = divisorTransform
        self.fakeParam = fakeParam
        print(f'{type(self).__name__} id {id(self)} init saving {type(self.divTrns).__name__} at {id(self.divTrns)}')

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        print(f'{type(self).__name__} id {id(self)} fit going to fit {type(self.divTrns).__name__} {id(self.divTrns)}')
        self.divisor_ = self.divTrns.fit(X).getDivisor()
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        print(f'{type(self).__name__} id {id(self)} transform')
        res = X.copy()
        res = res / self.divisor_
        print('_______________________________________')
        print(res)
        return res

    def anti_transform(self, X):
        res = X.copy()
        res = res * self.divisor_
        return res

    def score(self, X, y=None, sample_weight=None):
        return 1


x = pd.DataFrame([[i+j*10 for j in range(3)] for i in range(10)],columns=['A','B','C'])
dvT = DivisorTransform()
print(type(dvT).__name__)
pipe = Pipeline([('divisor',dvT),('normalization',NormalizationTransform(dvT, 0))])
res1 = pipe.fit_transform(x)
params = {'normalization__fakeParam':[0,1]}
gs = GridSearchCV(pipe,params,cv=TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=3).split(x))
print('Starting Grid Search')
gs.fit(x)
```

Thi produces as print:

```
Starting Grid Search
NormalizationTransform id 140321510292896 init saving NoneType at 94405154462352
NormalizationTransform id 140321722266344 init saving NoneType at 94405154462352
```

That shows the problem

Comment: Can you show the codes for these?

Comment: @VivekKumar done

Comment: Your DivisorTransform is not doing anything (transformation). So why is it included? You can simply move `self.divisor_ = X.max()` in `fit()` of `NormalizationTransform` and remove the `DivisorTransform` altogether (from the pipeline and from the `NormalizationTransform`). Or am I missing something?

Comment: @VivekKumar your question opens another problem `DivisorTransform` than should be used to denormalize the **test** set.

Comment: During the transformation of test set, fit will not be called, only `transform()` is called. So the `max()` value learnt from the training data will be used.

Comment: @VivekKumar the point is that at the end the score has to be computed using both standardized and destandardized data. So as I have to have a way to store the max and pass it to a regressor at the end of the pipeline. Maybe I should open a new post and reformulate the question?

Comment: Yes. You can edit this question and tell us what you want to actually do, with an example.